# Overriding Expressjs response in middleware is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I want to modify response body before returning it, i've used solution from  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33735452/5038921)

But it didn't work, here's my code:

app.js

```
function modify(req, res, next) {
  var json = res.json;
  console.log("step 1");
  res.json = function(data) {
    console.log("step 2");
    json.call(this, "modified");
  };
  next();
}
app.use(modify);
```

in router:

```
router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
  res.json('Welcome')
  next()
})
```

Middleware has been called but the override function (step 2) was never invoked, please tell me what's wrong with my code, thanks!

Comment: What does the `wrap` function do?

Comment: @Shaharyar just a function adding some information to the response body

Comment: add that function too in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use next() to only for passing to next function

```
router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    if(wantToStop=='true'){
       res.json('Welcome')
    }else{
      next()
   }

 })
```