# Monkeypatch res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

From a college suggestion and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732509/express-js-how-to-intercept-response-send-response-json)

I'm trying to monkey patch res.send but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
```

This is my code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next ) => {
    const oldSend = res.send;
    res.send = (data) => {
        console.log(data.length);
        oldSend(data);
    }
    next();
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
    at send (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:110:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/Users/code/js/hello/index.js:8:9)
    at app.get (/Users/code/js/hello/index.js:12:32)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/code/js/hello/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Where line 110 is:

```
res.send = function send(body) {
  var chunk = body;
  var encoding;
  var req = this.req; //<-- THIS 
  var type;

  // settings
  var app
....
```

Comment: Do you have a trace? At which line do you get it? Also, length is misspelled in your code.

Comment: Updated with the trace

Comment: Try `oldSend.apply(res, [data]);` instead of just calling `oldSend(data)`. I suspect the `this` reference was "lost" when you do patching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because methods are not tied to their instances in JavaScript.

If you call `a.fun()`, inside the function code, `this` will initially be set to `a`. But this happens only because `a` appears in the method call: `fun` is otherwise an arbitrary function that has no relationship with `a`.

In your case, this should work:

```
oldSend.call(res, data);
```

The point of `call()` is to set `this`.

Comment: This works. Also calling bind has the same effect. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the oldSend loses it's context(?)

If I add `bind(res)`:

```
const oldSend = res.send.bind(res);
```

The problem is gone.