# Access response status code/body after it's sent

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm trying to monitor the status codes of the responses sent by my express server which has quite a few routes. One way to do this would be to manually save the error code before I send it with `res.send()` but I'd rather have a cleaner way of doing this. I tried using a middleware that is called after the route handler but it doesnt get called, presumably because `res.send` ends the execution of middlewares. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express.js - how to intercept response.send() / response.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732509/express-js-how-to-intercept-response-send-response-json)

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

`res.send()` doesn't end the execution of middlewares, but the lack of calling `next()` will.  So, in your case, I think chaining another middleware after your route handler is the correct approach, just ensure it ends with calling `next()`.

Example:

```js
// router.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const routeHandler = require('../controllers/route-handler')
const logResponse = require('../middleware/log-response')
router.get('/', routeHandler, logResponse)
```

```js
// controllers/route-handler.js
function routeHandler(req, res, next) {
  // Do some stuff
  res.status(200).json({})
  return next() // <-- This is the key -- it will continue to the next  middleware
}

module.exports = {
  routeHandler
}
```

```js
// middleware/log-response.js
function logResponse(req, res, next) {
  console.log(res.status, res.statusText) // 200 OK
}

module.exports = {
  logResponse
}
```

Hope that helps!