# How to create Interceptor in Expressjs for sending token for each request and also refresh token on expire with Angular 6

Tags: node.js

From Angular 6 I am making an Http request to Expressjs,
Expressjs calls an API to get specific details

In-Depth Explanation:
I have created interceptor in Angular 6 but that is not passing access token for each request which I am making from express. So I am trying to create an interceptor in express which can send token for each API request and if a token is expired then it should call API to refresh the access token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express.js - how to intercept response.send() / response.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732509/express-js-how-to-intercept-response-send-response-json)

Comment: No. What i am asking is to create interceptor in nodejs. The one which you have shared link is completely different