# Why res. body is undefined in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why res. body is undefined in express
how can I get response body,
Is there something wrong?

```js
import {createProxyMiddleware} from 'http-proxy-middleware'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mung from "express-mung";

const app = express();


app.use(((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(res.body)

    next()
}))

app.get('/as', function (req, res, next) {

    res.send("123")
})
app.listen(3001, () => console.log('start in http://localhost:3001'))
```

Comment: Can youexplain your problem in little bit more detail?

Comment: I want to view the content of res.send in middleware and modify it, but the  result  res.body is always undefined

Comment: `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
})` this code is executed every time app receives a request. when you get a request through get you can see console.log(req) but in express it is from server side to sen data using res object, so its natural to get res.body undefined.http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.

ALso if it was a post request with some data then also you would be using req.body and not res.body. req object is what you get, res is what you send from server.

Comment: @edcjian Is the intention here to mutate the body before sending it back to the client? i.e. you want `res.body` to give you `"123"` after `res.send()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is what I expected and solved my problem

[express.js - how to intercept response.send() / response.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732509/express-js-how-to-intercept-response-send-response-json)

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let oldSend = res.send
    res.send = function(data) {
        console.log(data) // do something with the data
        res.send = oldSend // set function back to avoid the 'double-send'
        return res.send(data) // just call as normal with data
    }
    next()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't parsed the body data yet.

#### [req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`.

Express comes with two body parser method, try using them like this

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

> req = Request , res = Response

you need to log **req.body**

```
app.use(((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    next()
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

just check my logic if it helps you,

```js
app.post('/as', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

In-order to print something in console for req.body , u need to pass a "body"
from where u call this . eg refer screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f79Ey.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Express** not like **koa**, response has no **'body'** attribute, but you can create a custom middleware to resolve this, there is an example:

```js
const logResponseBodyMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const selfWrite = res.write
  const selfEnd = res.end
  const chunks = []

  res.write = (...args) => {
    const chunk = args[0]
    chunks.push(chunk)
    return selfWrite.apply(res, args)
  }
  res.end = (...args) => {
    const chunk = args[0]
    if (chunk) chunks.push(chunk)
    res.body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')
    selfEnd.apply(res, args)
  }

  next()
}

app.use(logResponseBodyMiddleware)
```

- Node.js: 12.21.0
- Express: 4.17.1

**reference**:

> [http_response_write](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)
>
> [http_response_end](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)