# res.send not getting executed in the middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

The thing I want to do is modify the response body.

For this I am using a middleware that gets called at every request.
To achieve it, I took a demo application from github https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar . I added a middleware in the server.js similar to the example given on [express logging response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body).

Still I am unable to modify the response body, as res.send = function (string) does not get called.

Below mentioned is the code. Please let me know what wrong am I doing here.

```
 var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
http = require('http'),
wine = require('./routes/wines');

var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser()), 
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(logResponseBody);
});

app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });
 function logResponseBody(req,res,next){
 var send = res.send; 
 console.log("send resp is: "+send);
 res.send = function (string) {
 var body = string instanceof Buffer ? string.toString() : string;
   console.log("Body found is: "+body);
   body = body.replace(/<\/head>/, function (w) {
   return 'Modified head' + w;
  });
 send.call(this, body);
 }; 
 res.on('finish', function(){
console.log("Finished " + res.headersSent); // for example
console.log("Finished " + res.statusCode);  // for example
})
next();
}
```

PS: I am starting a new thread for a similar question as I have less than 50 reputation.Therefore cant add comments there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add middleware to an express app is to use the app.use method, so you can remove the whole http.createServer block and replace it for something like

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  //do everything you want to happen on every request
  next();
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

For more info on app.use, check [the express app use documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use).

Comment: I have tried it using app.listen instead of http.listen but still its not working.

Comment: the important part here is to take out the contents of the callback in the listen method and put it in the app.use method