# Log all GraphQL responses with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I managed to setup logging graphQL errors with:

```js
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(request => {
  return {
    schema,
    rootValue: {
      request
    },
    formatError: error => {
      const params = {
        message  : error.message,
        locations: error.locations,
        stack    : error.stack
      };
      winston.error(`message: "${error.message}", QUERY: "${request.body.query}"`);
      // Optional ${request.body.operationName} ${request.body.variables}
      return (params);
    }
  }
}));
```

How can I set up a general function that can access the request and response, even when there is no error?

Edit: I've managed to log all requests by:

```js
function loggingMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.startsWith('/graphql')) {
    winston.debug('REQUEST: ', req.body);
  }
  next();
}
app.use(loggingMiddleware);
```

before I call `app.use('/graphql')`, but still don't know how to run a "post graphql handling" handler to log the response as well.

Comment: Thanks for posting about how you managed to logging. I find `req.body` to be undefined with the current version of `express-graphql` though (0.9.0).

Answer (score 6):

You can proxy the `req.send()` function in express.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let originalSend = res.send;
    res.send = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        originalSend.apply(res, Array.from(arguments));
    }
    next();
})
```

This is just to show you how you can achieve something like this.

I see you use winston, so I'd suggest you to use [express-winston](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/blob/master/Readme.md).

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body) out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this package to achieve what you want:
https://github.com/withspectrum/graphql-log

Also I use [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) and I added a date as prefix of my logs, here is a example code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const createGraphQLLogger = require('graphql-log');
    const debug = require('debug')('server:resolvers');
    debug.enabled = true;
    const logExecutions = createGraphQLLogger({
        prefix: new Date(),
        logger: debug
    })
    logExecutions(resolvers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. `express-graphql` provides an [`extensions`](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#providing-extensions) mechanism, which supplies you with the `result` directly as one of the parameters.

```js
app.use('/graphql', graphQLHTTP(request => {
  return {
    schema: ...,
    extensions({
      result,
    }) {
      console.log(result.data);
    },
  };
}));
```