# node/ loopback logging all response body

Tags: node.js, http, express, loopbackjs

in server.js file i have added the below code from [ref](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/23578738b4ec7211396d). it gives me req.body as expected. but is it possible to log the response.body as well? how.
i tried to print the res.body it gives me long object of response but not actual response body.

```
app.middleware('initial', function logResponse(req, res, next) {
  // install a listener for when the response is finished
  res.on('finish', function() {
    // the request was handled, print the log entry

    console.log(res.body, req.originalUrl, res.statusCode);
  });

  // resume the routing pipeline,
  // let other middleware to actually handle the request
  next();
});
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "log object of response"?

Comment: it was typo : long

Comment: Ok, as I understand you've got the web server and want to every response message sent by the server?

Comment: yes exactly ! !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express logging response body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late:  Although Loopback uses express this is a loopback specific question, so not a duplicate.  You need to access the current context not the response obj, the context will have the response obj.  A workaround is logging using a hook "afterRemote(**..." or enable enableHttpContext for middleware in config.json

```js
"remoting": {
    "context": {
      "enableHttpContext": true
    }
```