# How can I console.log the res.body in Express nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using  "express": "^4.16.2" and "morgan": "^1.9.1",
but I can't log the response body.
I troubleshooted by console.log the res.body after building the res. It can show the whole res, but if just log the res.body, it shows undefined.

```
  app.use(express.json());   //build-in
  app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));   
  app.use(morgan(loggerFormat, { stream: accessLogStream }));
......
//*****  Cannot get response body  */
// morgan.token('id', (req) => { return req.id; });
// morgan.token('reqBody', req => { return JSON.stringify(req.body) });
// morgan.token('resBody', (req, res) => {return JSON.stringify(res.body)});
// var loggerFormat = ':date[iso] :id :method :url \n :reqBody \n :status \n :resBody';
// app.use(morgan(loggerFormat, { stream: accessLogStream }));  // 3rd party

  app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateCourse(req.body);
  if(error) return res.status(400).json({"error": error.details[0].message});

  const course = {
     id: parseInt(courses[courses.length-1].id) + 1,
     name: req.body.name,
     tutor: req.body.tutor
  };

  courses.push(course);
  res.status(200).json(course);
  console.log(res); 
  console.log(res.body);
});
```

I try the solution provided by 
[Node.js + Express - How to log the request body and response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310461/node-js-express-how-to-log-the-request-body-and-response-body), but it doesn't help.

Comment: Why don't you configure Morgan to log the body?

Comment: console.log(res.body ) won't work here because this man  res.status(200).json(course) ends the request so if u want to see req.body in your console move the statement above this res.status(200).json(course)

Comment: I comment out the Morgan because it can't log the res body.  And I try to figure out where it is wrong by using console.log

Comment: Might following link could help, Seems same issue
[express-logging-response-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   console.log(res); 
   console.log(res.body)
  courses.push(course);
  res.status(200).json(course);
```

console.log the req.body before sending a response

Comment: Ok try using body parser module