# how can I get response body in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to save request a response body in my **NodeJS** API. I use **express**.
[image: express get response body]

I write tow middleware.
first: process the client request.

```
app.use((req, res,next) => {

res.status(404).json({
    errors: [{
            field: "url",
            message: "not found"
        }]
});

next();
```

});

second: log or save the request and response body.

```
app.use((req, res,next) => {

console.log(req.body);
console.log(res); //here I want get response body

});
```

> my question is how can I access to the response body in express? if there isn't any way how can I save request and response body in **NodeJS**?

Answer (score 3):

You should bind a callback for `finish` event of response

```
app.use((req, res,next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.on('finish', () => console.log(res)); //get response body in callback
});
```

because the response object is not fully available when the middleware is executed.

Comment: not work. it loges nothing.

Comment: @MohammadJavadAbbasi sorry, check out my latest edition

Comment: I just want response body. but this code get all method and data about response. and I can't find response body.

Comment: @MohammadJavadAbbasi check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310461/node-js-express-how-to-log-the-request-body-and-response-body/52311152