# Store morgan logs into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, morgan

I am using `morgan('dev')` for logging, but I want to store this object `"GET /users/get 200 195.315 ms - 393"` [in console log] into database.

like

```
- method : get 
- endpoint : /users/get
- status : 200
```

How can I get this object?
How to explode and insert data into field(method, endpoint, status) above on database?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a small middleware that will listen on ['finish'](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) event of Response and save the data into the database:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const method = req.method;
  const endpoint = req.originalUrl;

  res.on('finish', () => {
   const status = res.status;
   saveRequestDataToDatabase(method, endpoint, status);
   next();
  });
});
```

Comment: ok, what if i want to store request body and response to field? how to getting that?

Comment: If you are using `bodyparser` then you can access Request's body like `req.body`.  Getting the body of Response is not that easy because Response is a [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). Usually retrieving Response's body is done by monkey patching of `response.write` and `response.end` methods. You can see how it can be implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body) or [here](https://github.com/sirrodgepodge/morgan-body).

Answer (score 1):

> There are modules already out there that provide stream-compatible interfaces to known storages, such as Mongoose-Morgan which allows you to stream your Mongoose logs directly into MongoDB. However, if you can’t find a morgan-compatible module, you can simply write a function that returns a writable stream and sends the information where you need it.
> [Morgan NPM Logger – The Beginner’s Guide](https://coralogix.com/blog/morgan-npm-logger-the-complete-guide/)

Create a new named format:

```
const morgan = require('morgan')
const Writable = require("stream").Writable
morgan.token("custom", "-method: :method -endpoint: :url -status: status")
```

Use the new format by name:

```
 class MyStream extends Writable {
    write(line) {
    //here you send the log line to wherever you need
       console.log("Logger:: ", line)
    }
  }
  let writer = new MyStream()
 
 app.use(morgan(‘custom’, {stream: write}))
```