# How do I see the actual HTTP response going out from Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm experiencing intermittent Proxy errors for an Express app behind an Apache proxy. These only happen when making the request through the proxy, and only when the browser does the request. The proxy says that it can't understand the response from Express.

I'd like to see the actual HTTP response sent by Express, so how could I get it's content to log it somewhere? Note that this *must* include headers as they are sent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express logging response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body)

Comment: No, it doesn't include headers.

Comment: Everything else you can read from `res` object - headers, url, method etc