# nestjs middleware get request/response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, nestjs

I am working with nestjs for a project, and want to log as much information as possible, one such thing being the body of the response and request of every http request. I made a nest middleware for that end:

```
import {token} from 'gen-uid';
import { inspect } from 'util';
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, MiddlewareFunction } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Stream } from 'stream';
import { createWriteStream, existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    logfileStream: Stream;

    constructor() {
        if (!existsSync('./logs')) mkdirSync('./logs');
        this.logfileStream = createWriteStream("./logs/serviceName-"+ new Date().toISOString() + ".log", {flags:'a'});
    }

resolve(...args: any[]): MiddlewareFunction {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        let reqToken = token();
        let startTime = new Date();
        let logreq = {
            "@timestamp": startTime.toISOString(),
            "@Id": reqToken,
            query: req.query,
            params: req.params,
            url: req.url,
            fullUrl: req.originalUrl,
            method: req.method,
            headers: req.headers,
            _parsedUrl: req._parsedUrl,
        }

        console.log(
            "timestamp: " + logreq["@timestamp"] + "\t" + 
            "request id: " + logreq["@Id"] + "\t" + 
            "method:  " + req.method + "\t" +
            "URL: " + req.originalUrl);

        this.logfileStream.write(JSON.stringify(logreq));

        const cleanup = () => {
            res.removeListener('finish', logFn)
            res.removeListener('close', abortFn)
            res.removeListener('error', errorFn)
        }

        const logFn = () => {
            let endTime = new Date();
            cleanup()
            let logres = {
                "@timestamp": endTime.toISOString(),
                "@Id": reqToken,
                "queryTime": endTime.valueOf() - startTime.valueOf(),
            }
            console.log(inspect(res));
        }

        const abortFn = () => {
            cleanup()
            console.warn('Request aborted by the client')
        }

        const errorFn = err => {
            cleanup()
            console.error(`Request pipeline error: ${err}`)
        }

        res.on('finish', logFn) // successful pipeline (regardless of its response)
        res.on('close', abortFn) // aborted pipeline
        res.on('error', errorFn) // pipeline internal error

        next();
    };
}
}
```

Then I set this middleware as a global middleware to log all request, but looking at the res and req object, neither of them have a property.

In the code sample I set the response object to be printed, running a hello world endpoint on my project that returns {"message":"Hello World"}
I get the following output:

> timestamp: 2019-01-09T00:37:00.912Z   request id: 2852f925f987    method:  GET    URL: /hello-world
>
> ServerResponse {
>     domain: null,
>     _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
>     _eventsCount: 1,
>     _maxListeners: undefined,
>     output: [],
>     outputEncodings: [],
>     outputCallbacks: [],
>     outputSize: 0,
>     writable: true,
>     _last: false,
>     upgrading: false,
>     chunkedEncoding: false,
>     shouldKeepAlive: true,
>     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
>     sendDate: true,
>     _removedConnection: false,
>     _removedContLen: true,
>     _removedTE: true,
>     _contentLength: 0,
>     _hasBody: false,
>     _trailer: '',
>     finished: true,
>     _headerSent: true,
>     socket: null,
>     connection: null,
>     _header: 'HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nETag: W/"19-c6Hfa5VVP+Ghysj+6y9cPi5QQbk"\r\nDate: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 00:37:00 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
>     _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
>     _sent100: false,
>     _expect_continue: false,
>     req: 
>      IncomingMessage {
>        _readableState: 
>         ReadableState {
>           objectMode: false,
>           highWaterMark: 16384,
>           buffer: [Object],
>           length: 0,
>           pipes: null,
>           pipesCount: 0,
>           flowing: true,
>           ended: true,
>           endEmitted: false,
>           reading: false,
>           sync: true,
>           needReadable: false,
>           emittedReadable: true,
>           readableListening: false,
>           resumeScheduled: true,
>           destroyed: false,
>           defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
>           awaitDrain: 0,
>           readingMore: true,
>           decoder: null,
>           encoding: null },
>        readable: true,
>        domain: null,
>        _events: {},
>        _eventsCount: 0,
>        _maxListeners: undefined,
>        socket: 
>         Socket {
>           connecting: false,
>           _hadError: false,
>           _handle: [Object],
>           _parent: null,
>           _host: null,
>           _readableState: [Object],
>           readable: true,
>           domain: null,
>           _events: [Object],
>           _eventsCount: 10,
>           _maxListeners: undefined,
>           _writableState: [Object],
>           writable: true,
>           allowHalfOpen: true,
>           _bytesDispatched: 155,
>           _sockname: null,
>           _pendingData: null,
>           _pendingEncoding: '',
>           server: [Object],
>           _server: [Object],
>           _idleTimeout: 5000,
>           _idleNext: [Object],
>           _idlePrev: [Object],
>           _idleStart: 12562,
>           _destroyed: false,
>           parser: [Object],
>           on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
>           _paused: false,
>           read: [Function],
>           _consuming: true,
>           _httpMessage: null,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 151,
>           [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 153,
>           [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 151 },
>        connection: 
>         Socket {
>           connecting: false,
>           _hadError: false,
>           _handle: [Object],
>           _parent: null,
>           _host: null,
>           _readableState: [Object],
>           readable: true,
>           domain: null,
>           _events: [Object],
>           _eventsCount: 10,
>           _maxListeners: undefined,
>           _writableState: [Object],
>           writable: true,
>           allowHalfOpen: true,
>           _bytesDispatched: 155,
>           _sockname: null,
>           _pendingData: null,
>           _pendingEncoding: '',
>           server: [Object],
>           _server: [Object],
>           _idleTimeout: 5000,
>           _idleNext: [Object],
>           _idlePrev: [Object],
>           _idleStart: 12562,
>           _destroyed: false,
>           parser: [Object],
>           on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
>           _paused: false,
>           read: [Function],
>           _consuming: true,
>           _httpMessage: null,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 151,
>           [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 153,
>           [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 151 },
>        httpVersionMajor: 1,
>        httpVersionMinor: 1,
>        httpVersion: '1.1',
>        complete: true,
>        headers: 
>         { host: 'localhost:5500',
>           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
>           accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>           'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
>           'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
>           connection: 'keep-alive',
>           'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
>           'if-none-match': 'W/"19-c6Hfa5VVP+Ghysj+6y9cPi5QQbk"' },
>        rawHeaders: 
>         [ 'Host',
>           'localhost:5500',
>           'User-Agent',
>           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',
>           'Accept',
>           'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>           'Accept-Language',
>           'en-US,en;q=0.5',
>           'Accept-Encoding',
>           'gzip, deflate',
>           'Connection',
>           'keep-alive',
>           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
>           '1',
>           'If-None-Match',
>           'W/"19-c6Hfa5VVP+Ghysj+6y9cPi5QQbk"' ],
>        trailers: {},
>        rawTrailers: [],
>        upgrade: false,
>        url: '/hello-world',
>        method: 'GET',
>        statusCode: null,
>        statusMessage: null,
>        client: 
>         Socket {
>           connecting: false,
>           _hadError: false,
>           _handle: [Object],
>           _parent: null,
>           _host: null,
>           _readableState: [Object],
>           readable: true,
>           domain: null,
>           _events: [Object],
>           _eventsCount: 10,
>           _maxListeners: undefined,
>           _writableState: [Object],
>           writable: true,
>           allowHalfOpen: true,
>           _bytesDispatched: 155,
>           _sockname: null,
>           _pendingData: null,
>           _pendingEncoding: '',
>           server: [Object],
>           _server: [Object],
>           _idleTimeout: 5000,
>           _idleNext: [Object],
>           _idlePrev: [Object],
>           _idleStart: 12562,
>           _destroyed: false,
>           parser: [Object],
>           on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
>           _paused: false,
>           read: [Function],
>           _consuming: true,
>           _httpMessage: null,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 151,
>           [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
>           [Symbol(asyncId)]: 153,
>           [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 151 },
>        _consuming: false,
>        _dumped: true,
>        next: [Function: next],
>        baseUrl: '',
>        originalUrl: '/hello-world',
>        _parsedUrl: 
>         Url {
>           protocol: null,
>           slashes: null,
>           auth: null,
>           host: null,
>           port: null,
>           hostname: null,
>           hash: null,
>           search: null,
>           query: null,
>           pathname: '/hello-world',
>           path: '/hello-world',
>           href: '/hello-world',
>           _raw: '/hello-world' },
>        params: {},
>        query: {},
>        res: [Circular],
>        body: {},
>        route: Route { path: '/hello-world', stack: [Array], methods: [Object] } },
>     locals: {},
>     statusCode: 304,
>     statusMessage: 'Not Modified',
>     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: 
>      { 'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ],
>        etag: [ 'ETag', 'W/"19-c6Hfa5VVP+Ghysj+6y9cPi5QQbk"' ] } }

In no place in the response object does the {"message":"Hello World"} message appears, I would like to know how to obtain the body from the res and req objects if it is possible please.

Note: I know that nestjs has `Interceptors`, but following what the documentation says, middleware should be the solution for this problem.

Comment: Still having problems? :-)

Answer (score 5):

I've run against this question accidentally, it was listed in "related" to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636005/overloaded-routes-in-nestjs-controller).

I can extend [Kim Kern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54104120/1114686) a bit more, about responses.

Problem with response is that response body ain't a property of response object, but *stream*. To be able to get it, you need to override methods, which writes to that stream.

Like Kim Kern already said, you can look onto [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body), there is accepted answer how to do this.

Or you can take [express-mung](https://github.com/richardschneider/express-mung) middleware, which will do it for you, for example:

```
var mung = require('express-mung');
app.use(mung.json(
  function transform(body, req, res) {
    console.log(body); // or whatever logger you use
    return body;
  }
));
```

And there are two other different ways, which NestJS can offer you:

- [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors), like you said. There is example of `LoggingInterceptor` in documentation.
- You can write decorator for controller's methods, which will intercept their responses.

```js
import { isObservable, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * Logging decorator for controller's methods
 */
export const LogReponse = (): MethodDecorator =>
  (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {

    // save original method
    const original = descriptor.value;

    // replace original method
    descriptor.value = function() { // must be ordinary function, not arrow function, to have `this` and `arguments`

      // get original result from original method
      const ret = original.apply(this, arguments);

      // if it is null or undefined -> just pass it further
      if (ret == null) {
        return ret;
      }

      // transform result to Observable
      const ret$ = convert(ret);

      // do what you need with response data
      return ret$.pipe(
        map(data => {
          console.log(data); // or whatever logger you use
          return data;
        })
      );
    };

    // return modified method descriptor
    return descriptor;
  };

function convert(value: any) {
  // is this already Observable? -> just get it
  if (isObservable(value)) {
    return value;
  }

  // is this array? -> convert from array
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return from(value);
  }

  // is this Promise-like? -> convert from promise, also convert promise result
  if (typeof value.then === 'function') {
    return from(value).pipe(mergeMap(convert));
  }

  // other? -> create stream from given value
  return of(value);
}
```

Note though, that this will executes *before interceptors*, because this decorator change methods behaviour.

And I don't think this is nice way to do logging, just mentioned it for variety :)

Answer (score 2):

It's incredible how something so trivial is so hard to do.

The easier way to log response body is to **create an Interceptor** (https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors):

**AppModule**:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: HttpInterceptor,
    }
]
```

**HttpInterceptor**:

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, Logger, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(HttpInterceptor.name);

  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler<any>,
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(data => {
        this.logger.debug(data);
        return data;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By using this I can see successful responses only, as data structures (I'm using GraphQL). If, say, an auth guard blocks the query (`message: "Unauthorized"` being the response), the interceptor is not invoked. Is there a known way how to access the raw response body after all in-app processing has taken place? I want to log actual details on what could have went wrong.

Comment: @AlexFortuna did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @wopolow Don't think so… Had to hide the pain, usual thing with Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

The *response* body will not be accessible as a property. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19215042/4694994) for a solution.

You should however be able to access the *request* body with `req.body` since nest uses `bodyParser` by default.