# Why do I get two responses for one request in node.js terminal

Tags: node.js, express

// app.js code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/friends",function(req,res){
    var friends = ["tony","miranda","pierre","lilly"]
    res.render("friends",{friends:friends});
});

app.post("/addfriend",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);

    res.send("You have reached the post route")
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server Started!");

});
```

// friends.ejs code

```
<h1>Friends</h1>

<% friends.forEach(function(friend){ %>
    <li>I Have a Friend = <%= friend %></li>
<% }) %>

<form action="/addfriend" method="POST">

    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="newfriend">
    <button>Add Me</button>
</form>
```

The response I get:

```
Server Started!
{}
{ newfriend: 'ahnaf' }
```

please review the code above and I created an express app whenever I request for one response I get two response.In the response section mentioned here the extra response is the empty object.Please help me out

Comment: What action do you take in the browser that generates the empty object in the node.js console?  Do you have any Javascript in the web page that is participating in sending your form to the server?

Comment: yesss I send a single input to the server

Comment: Please read the question I asked in my previous and answer it.  What specific action do you do in the browser that causes this?  Press a button?  Type a URL?  Hit Return?  Also, is there Javascript active in the page?  If so, show it to use please.

Comment: try Commenting  line res.send("You have reached the post route")

Comment: Please check this code i think thats what you want.

Comment: code link https://github.com/cemtorun/learning_web_dev/blob/master/Section%2026:%20Intermediate%20Express/friendsProject/app.js

Comment: check your code you should put ; after every line of code. you are logging request where is code for your /addfriend code. When

Comment: @jfriend00 there is no javascript required to post. You post directly by app.post("/addfriend", function(req,res){
 // makes it so we can see what the post req is sending to server
 var newFriend = req.body.newfriend; // body parser needs to see req in js form from express
 // body parser parsed express obj to js object
 friends.push(newFriend); 
 res.redirect("/friends"); //after running add friends, it also runs /friends to update the list
});

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code https://github.com/cemtorun/learning_web_dev/blob/master/Section%2026:%20Intermediate%20Express/friendsProject/app.js

check your code you should put ; after every line of code.
you are logging request where is code for your /addfriend code.
When you are posting something to the page. You are refreshing the whole page.
So one is getting a new friend
/addfriend does show you body 
{ newfriend: 'ahnaf' }

then you have this line res.send .comment this and write it like this

you can write a middleware to intercept data written to the response. Make sure you disable app.compress().

```
function logResponseBody(req, res, next) {
  var oldWrite = res.write,
      oldEnd = res.end;

  var chunks = [];

  res.write = function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);

    oldWrite.apply(res, arguments);
  };

  res.end = function (chunk) {
    if (chunk)
      chunks.push(chunk);

    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
    console.log(req.path, body);

    oldEnd.apply(res, arguments);
  };

  next();
}
```

then use like this.

```
app.use(logResponseBody);
```

Comment: `app.post("/addfriend", ...)` just does a `res.send()`.  It, by itself does not cause a double page refresh.  That is likely  caused by something else in the page that the OP is not showing us.  No middleware like this is needed to solve this problem.  Not sure where you got this idea from.

Comment: @jfriend00  I don't know why re you so confident?.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body

Comment: Yeah, but what does that have to do with this problem in the slightest?  What evidence do you see in this question that it has anything at all to do with this answer?

Comment: @jfriend00 he is saying he is getting two response. in face he is not getting two response. he is logging  request req.body  which is that json.

Comment: @jfriend00 this is what he is trying to codehttps://github.com/cemtorun/learning_web_dev/blob/master/Section%2026:%20Intermediate%20Express/friendsProject/friends.ejs